# Where To Call Custom Method? viewDidLoad, viewWillLoad

Tags: iphone, methods, viewdidload

I am loading some info from a server. I have created a separate method to do this. I am then calling [self myCustomMethod] to run the method. No matter where I call [self myCustomMethod] (initWithNibName, viewDidLoad, viewWillLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear), the custom method is getting called twice - what's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't instantiating your `UIViewController` twice? Or call any of these methods yourself at some point? `initWithNibName` will only be called once, the other methods may be called more than once in the life span of a `UIViewController`. This doesn't mean however that `initWithNibName` is the best place to call your method. It depends on exactly what it does, for example, wether it needs to do anything with the view.